Changing the input layout of an ONNX model from NCHW to NHWC
I have an ONNX model with an input shape of (1, 1, 28, 28), which is in an NCHW layout.
Is there any way that I can convert the model to take input data in the NHWC layout, i.e., as (1, 28, 28, 1)?
The model is loaded from a file using the following code: model_obj = onnx.load(model_path)
A method to modify and convert the ONNX file can also be helpful.

I think that in ONNX2Keras they take care of this swapping. You should take a look at how they implement change_ordering=True

Thank you @SomethingSomething, I will look into it. But in fact, I don't have access to the source Keras model.

To be sure, you want change the shapes of all intermediate layers - because they depend on you input shape -  then right ?

@PlainRavioli Actually, I would rather have all intermediate layers in NHWC as well. But that's the second thing that should be handled. For now, any changes in the internal layout are fine as long as the input layout becomes NHWC.

Ok, I see. To get a bit more context, why isn't changing the shape in code before using the onnx model a viable solution for you ?

@PlainRavioli The onnx model is a pre-trained model received as a file. What I do next is to read operations and parameters in the model and create another list of operations to be used by another script. That second script only supports inputs and operations in the NHWC layout.

ONNX only supports NCHW, however you could modify the model to take NHWC then add a transpose.
I don't have examples to show you, however I got a couple of resources that you may find useful.

In the ProViz examples for running ONNX on the GPU there is an example of a CUDA kernel that does NHWC to NCHW (and the other way around) https://github.com/NVIDIA/ProViz-AI-Samples/blob/master/onnxruntime_cpp_samples/cuda_provider/src/FormatConversion.cu

ProViz blogpost about the repository above (they briefly mention the conversion an how you can deal with it): https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/end-to-end-ai-for-nvidia-based-pcs-cuda-and-tensorrt-execution-providers-in-onnx-runtime/#nhwc_format


Sorry for not giving the most useful answer, but this is all I know about the topic.
(Edited) Note: These examples are in C++, I know you asked for python but this is what I found, nonetheless I think they are useful.
